# FileUploadHandler.ashx taking 99 seconds to process every continuous 5th Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, generic-handler

I'm having a FileUploadHandler.ashx in a web service to upload files to server in win forms application.

Even if FileUploadHandler made async / sync (tried both), it's taking time for every 5th Request...

I've a large no.of files, looping them to upload and for every consecutive 5th Request takes so much time....

I've created a log file to check which request is taking time as it follows below:

Request 1; Time Taken: 0.0717544 
Request 2; Time Taken: 0.019239
Request 3; Time Taken: 0.0297877 
Request 4; Time Taken: 0.0041714
Request 5; Time Taken: 99.9442763 
Request 6; Time Taken: 0.031179
Request 7; Time Taken: 0.0332562 
Request 8; Time Taken: 0.0037856
Request 9; Time Taken: 0.0283765 
Request 10; Time Taken: 99.9690294

My FileUploadHandler.ashx code as follows:

```
 /// <summary>
/// Summary description for FileUploadHandler
/// </summary>
public class FileUploadHandler : IHttpAsyncHandler
{
    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
    {
        AsynchOperation asynch = new AsynchOperation(cb, context, extraData);
        asynch.StartAsyncWork();
        return asynch;
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class AsynchOperation : IAsyncResult
{
    private bool _completed;
    private Object _state;
    private AsyncCallback _callback;
    private HttpContext _context;

    private GCloudUploadingModel gclouduploadingdatamodel;

    bool IAsyncResult.IsCompleted { get { return _completed; } }
    WaitHandle IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle { get { return null; } }
    Object IAsyncResult.AsyncState { get { return _state; } }
    bool IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously { get { return false; } }

    public AsynchOperation(AsyncCallback callback, HttpContext context, Object state)
    {
        _callback = callback;
        _context = context;
        _state = state;
        _completed = false;
    }




    public void StartAsyncWork()
    {
        try
        {

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(StartAsyncTask), null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            // SEND ERROR MAIL TO TECHNICAL TEAM
            using (CommonBussinessAccess ErrorSending = new CommonBussinessAccess())
            {
                ErrorSending.SendFailureInfoEmailToTechnicalTeam(new PracticeModel(), this.GetType().Name, "StartAsyncWork", ex.Message, ex, new EMRWebExceptionTraceLogModel());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _completed = true;
            _callback(this);
        }


    }

  private void StartAsyncTask(Object workItemState)
  {
        try
        {
                  //Uploading code....
        }
        finally
        {

        }
  }
```

Please Help...

Answer (score 3):

It happens based on [Failure Settings for an Application Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/failure).

- `rapidFailProtectionInterval`: *Specifies the number of minutes before the failure count for a process is reset.*
- `rapidFailProtectionMaxCrashes`: *Specifies the maximum number of failures that are allowed within the number of minutes specified by the `rapidFailProtectionInterval` attribute.*

The default value for both attributes is 5. It means if you have 5 unhandled exceptions in less than 5 minutes, then the application will restart.

if you are going to change those values using IIS Manager, then you can find those settings by selecting the application pool of your application → *Advanced Settings* → `Maximum Failures` and `Failure Interval (minutes)` in property grid:

[image]

Comment: But I ain't getting any exception in service, any other causes for pool restarting problem ??

Comment: There are multiple reasons for an application restart, for example writing something in application directory. But it will restart the application immediately. Since your application is restarting in every 5 requests, to me it's a symptom of having 5 unhandled exceptions in less than 5 minutes.